# Concatenate/Join/Merge two Dataframes with one missing column

Tags: python, pandas, date, merge, concatenation

I know the issue could have been already asked but I checked them all and I think my case is different (be kind please). So I have 2 datasets, the first one is the test dataset and the second one is the prediction (predicted values, that is why there is no data column) that I have saved in a dataframe. I want to merge both and have a dataframe like the one in the second image I posted.
About the date column ... is there any tip/trick I can use here. 
Thanks

[image: Dataframes]
[image: output]

here my line of code

```
result = pd.concat([test_df, pred_df], axis=1).reindex(test_df.index)
result
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is most likely because your dataframes have different indices. 
Do:

```py
pred_df.index = test_df.index
result = pd.concat([test_df, pred_df], axis=1).reindex(test_df.index)
```

Comment: Thanks ... I was closer(but in my head, lol). I was thinking about dealing with the index but I didn't know how. Thks